# Log Reuqests made by OWASP ZAP API scanning

Tags: docker, api, owasp, scanning, zap

I have a local OpenApi schema that I want to scan with [OWASP ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2017-06-19-scanning-apis-with-zap/) using their docker image. However, the report I get does not show me whether ZAP forms correct request bodies. Is there any way to log the requests made by zap in order to overlook the requests? I also tried manually editing their [zap-api-scan.py](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/main/docker/zap-api-scan.py) file but cannot make it work.

Comment: Coincidentally I'm looking at this at the moment. I hope to document something before too long, but it all depends on what else comes up...

Comment: @SimonBennetts Were you able to take a look at this already? 
It would help my project a lot.

Comment: Yes! I documented it all here https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/diagnosing-problems/ :D